# Don't Start PHP Session on Wordpress Post Type of Post

Tags: php, wordpress, session, e-commerce

On Wordpress, I'm using an e-comerce plugin which starts a php session on every page, but my caching solution will not cache a page or post once a php session starts.

I've successfully stopped the session from starting on the homepage with:

```
function no_start_session( $start_session ) {
if ( '/' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
            $start_session = false;
        }
}
add_filter( 'plugin_start_session', 'no_start_session', 10, 1 );
```

Now I want the same behavior to happen on every Wordpress post on my blog (not pages, just posts) but there's no way to easily target all of these at once via the URL because my URL scheme is [www.thesitename.com/the-post-name](http://www.thesitename.com/the-post-name)

I tried adding this to the function:

```
if ( is_singular() ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type ) {
        $start_session = false;
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. Is there a way to make sure that this PHP session doesn't start on all posts without changing the URL scheme?

Comment: _“But it does not work.”_ - have you tried to figure out why? Does `is_singular` return true at this point as it is supposed to? Is `$post` already set at this point?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this but as far as I can tell, a conditional like is_singular is not available at this point, so the session is created before the page can even be tested to see if is_singular is true or not.